speed of AFL fuzzing concern
Is it normal that WinAFL in this case takes so much time to find a crash with such a simple program like test_gdiplus.exe which comes by default with WinAFL and only weights 13 KB? Like in this screenshot only a few minutes have passed but I remember running this for 3 hours and it still found 0 crashes
here's the command I used
afl-fuzz -i C:\Users\andye\Desktop\inputs -o out -D C:\Users\andye\Desktop\DynamoRIO\bin64 -t 20000 -- -coverage_module test_gdiplus.exe -coverage_module gdiplus.dll -coverage_module WindowsCodecs.dll -fuzz_iterations 5000 -target_module test_gdiplus.exe -target_offset 0x1270 -nargs 2 -- test_gdiplus.exe @@

and here's a screenshot of my progress
enter image description here
I already tried adding a significant amount of seed data like at least a 719 KB to the input folder, and still I see practically 0 progress in finding crashes
